# LastModifiedFileListFilter not working as expected

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

```
public FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec rtwTifFileSharePoller() {
    CompositeFileListFilter<File> allFilters = new CompositeFileListFilter<>(); 

    allFilters.addFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.tif")); 
    allFilters.addFilter(new LastModifiedFileListFilter(120));

    return Files
            .inboundAdapter(new File(rtwSharedPath))
            .filter(allFilters)
            .preventDuplicates(true);
}
```

Test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class RTWFlowsTest {

RTWFlows rtwFlows = new RTWFlows();

@Test
public void rtwTifFileSharePoller() {
    System.out.println("executing test");

    FileReadingMessageSource getFile = rtwFlows.rtwTifFileSharePoller().get(); 

    Message<File> msg = null; 
    while( (msg = getFile.receive()) != null)
        msg.getHeaders().forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + value));
    } 
}
```

I edited a tif file, and immediately ran the test case, and that was listed in the files too. Not sure why recently edited files (within 2 mins), were also listed.

Comment: Works for me well. You might need to share some simple project to determine the issue. Might be the fact that you use such a version where `preventDuplicates(true)` overrides the `.filter(allFilters)`. Or something else is with your configuration...

Comment: I have commented out the preventDuplicates(true), but still getting as below: 
file_originalFile: \\localhost\file-inbound\recently_modified.tif
id: b17c7377-0a56-7e73-6ae8-ed80c8dc4a5c
file_name: recently_modified.tif
file_relativePath: recently_modified.tif
timestamp: 1551768847030
file modified date: 1551768548151
Current Time: 1551768847030

Comment: might it be because of using UDP path?, clearly the file is within modified time of 2 mins

Comment: I’m not sure what is UDP path, but if you don’t want to share a project with us, then consider to debug `FileReadingMessageSource` including filters to the culprit